# Can't set NSSlider value in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, preferences, nsslider

I need to set a slider in preferences window of  a cocoa application.

If I set the NSSlider in awakeFromNib like so

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

[thresholdSlider setInValue:9];
```

}

the preference window updates with the value when opened.

Though, since it is a preference window, I need to register the Value with NSUserDefault, so when the application at launch  would run :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

[thresholdSlider setValue:[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] forKey:kthresh];
NSLog( @"%@",[thresholdSlider objectValue]);
```

}

But I cant even set the slider value in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

[thresholdSlider setIntValue:9];

NSLog( @“%d”,[thresholdSlider intValue]);}
```

returns 0 and slider is set to minimum value(set in IB) in the preferences window.

Where can I call the `[thresholdSlider setValue:[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] forKey:kthresh];` to get the slider updated with the user value on last application quit?

The code edited according to Vadian proposition :

```
+(void)initialize{
NSDictionary *dicDefault = @{@"kthresh":@9};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]registerDefaults:dicDefault];}`

`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification{   
  `//Preferences
NSInteger thresholdValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"kthresh"];`

thresholdSlider.integerValue = thresholdValue;}`

`-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSUserDefaults *defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:thresholdSlider.integerValue forKey:@"kthresh"];
[defaults synchronize];}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppDelegate as soon as possible register the key value pair with a default value. This value is always used if no custom value has been written to disk yet.

```
NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{@"kthresh" : @9};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

Then set the value of the slider wherever you want, consider the syntax

```
NSInteger thresholdValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"kthresh"];
thresholdSlider.integerValue = thresholdValue;
```

To write the value to disk use this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ;
[defaults setInteger:thresholdSlider.integerValue forKey:@"kthresh"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

> **Do not use `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` to talk to `NSUserDefaults`**

Alternatively use Cocoa bindings and bind the key `integerValue` to the `NSUserDefaultsController` instance in Interface Builder.

Comment: The cocoa binding solution works, but the code does not , I edited my answer showing your solution so you can see where I call the functions. Although thank you I was also forgetting to call ` synchronise`!

Comment: Actually the code to register the default value(s) can be also in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, it must be ensured that it's executed before retrieving the values the first time. In `+initialize` you have to check for the current class e.g. `if (self == [AppDelegate class]) {` because `+initialize` is called multiple times. The code to read and write from and to `NSUserDefaults` is standard code and is supposed to work.

Comment: Well finally found out the issue was coming from the xib file not from the code. it works now, both ways.

Answer (score 0):

`[thresholdSlider setValue:[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] forKey:kthresh];`

should be

`[thresholdSlider setObjectValue:[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kthresh]];`

Comment: Thank you indeed my declaration was not right. Though still not working as I mentioned in the question, even if not using`NSUserDefaults`  the fonction [thresholdSlider setIntValue:9] is only changing the slider value if put in awakeFromNIb{} not in applicationDidFinishLaunching{}. Though I have other functions in applicationDidFinishLaunching, and they all get called properly. Im puzzled.